# VirtualTimeScheduler for testing Akka.NET?

Tags: unit-testing, system.reactive, akka.net

When we are testing Rx.NET code we can use TestScheduler that is implementing VirtualTimeScheduler and it allow us to create virtual timeline of events (CreateColdObservable) that occur in system and than test the state of the system in some point of times using methods like AdvanceTo.
I’m wondering if there is some equivalent in Akka.Net for testing system using some king of virtual timeline like in Rx.Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While testing your actors using Akka.TestKit, your actor system is configured to make use of [TestScheduler](http://api.getakka.net/docs/stable/html/DEC8F1E6.htm), which has `Advance`/`AdvanceTo` methods allowing moving forward in time. It's directly inspired by the VirtualTimeScheduler known from the Rx.NET.

Keep in mind that TestScheduler has limited usage: AFAIK it's only used in context of scheduling future events using i.e. `Context.System.Scheduler.ScheduleTellxxx` methods. It doesn't affect other time-based actions happening inside actor system.

Comment: It looks good but is there any information about using this TestScheduler with Akka.Net? I only found one example on the end of this article but I would like to learn more https://petabridge.com/blog/how-to-unit-test-akkadotnet-actors-akka-testkit/